# Removing Linebreak in Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is probably an incredibly simple answer, but I don't have a clue what I'm doing and can't find answers that work. Trying to get this to say "Currently Booking Next-Month" on one line, but there is a linebreak between "currently booking" and the month.

```html
    <html>
    <body>
    <h2>Currently Booking<h2 id="currentbooking"></h2>
    <script>
    var d = new Date();
    var months = ["February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December", "January"];
    document.getElementById("currentbooking").innerHTML = months[d.getMonth()];
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

What am I doing wrong? I got it to work for the copyright:

```
&copy; 2010<script>new Date().getFullYear()>2010&&document.write("-"+new Date().getFullYear());</script>, Company.
```

But can't figure out how to do it for the month.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try this: <h2>Currently Booking - <span id="currentbooking"></span></h2>

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You have two `<h2>` but only one `</h2>`

Answer (score 2):

Your `<h2>` tag is missing a closing tag. It would be a better idea if you just replace the stray `<h2 id="currentbooking">` tag nested inside your outer `<h2>` element with a `<span id="currentbooking">` tag instead since `<h2>` is a **block level element** and will take full-width by default.

```js
var d = new Date();
var months = ["February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December", "January"];
document.getElementById("currentbooking").innerHTML = months[d.getMonth()];
```

```html
<h2>Currently Booking <span id="currentbooking"></span></h2>
```

Comment: @hannah Glad I could help :) Do mark this as the correct answer if it helped you solve your issue. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be issue with your tags
Try this:

```
<h2>Currently Booking<span id="currentbooking"></span></h2>
```

Your rest of the code will remain same.

Span is a good way for inline text

Comment: If you downvote these answers, please also give feedback to the answerer so they know why they're being downvoted. This answer appears to be mostly correctly so its not clear why they are negative votes currently.

Comment: @justin.m.chase Simply pointing out a typo may answer the question, however it isn't useful for future visitors. Typo questions should be closed so that users looking for answers to real problems can find useful questions.

Comment: Well if the answer to the question is actually to correct a typo then the question itself should probably closed not the answer. Please don't downvote people providing correct answers.

Comment: I downvoted this post, because it isn't useful. I didn't downvote "people", and my reasoning was not related to the "correctness" of the answer. "correctness" is not the only metric that downvotes are for. @justin.m.chase

Comment: @KevinB Except it wasn't a typo mate :) Adding the missing `</h2>` still won't fix his issue of in-lining his text elements :) Our answers were focusing more on that rather than the typo which didn't really matter considering what the OP wanted. Cheers.